# Before insert trigger creation is failing MariaDB

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this insert trigger. Attempting to read the last row of the target table and set a status accordingly. The error message points me to the manual which is where I started;) .. The component queries work but put together not so much ..

```
    MariaDB [tide]> desc Marsh; 
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
    | Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
    | time   | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | current_timestamp() |       |
    | Sensor | int(3)       | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
    | NOAA   | decimal(3,2) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
    | rNum   | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
    | state  | varchar(5)   | NO   |     | slack               |       |
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

my trigger

```
   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER trend_before_insert
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON Marsh FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   DECLARE LASTREAD decimal(3,2) DEFAULT 0
   SELECT NOAA
   INTO LASTREAD
   FROM Marsh
   WHERE time in (select max(time) from Marsh);
   IF NOAA > LASTREAD THEN
   SET state = 'flow';
   END IF;
   IF NOAA < LASTREAD THEN       
   SET state = "ebb";
   END IF;
   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
```

A sample of the data:

```
    | 2021-05-04 12:25:28 |    175 | 1.26 |    6 | slack |
    | 2021-05-04 12:35:31 |    175 | 1.26 |    1 | slack |
    | 2021-05-04 12:45:28 |    175 | 1.26 |    2 | slack |
```

The key query:
MariaDB [tide]> SELECT NOAA from Marsh where time in (select max(time) from Marsh);

```
    +------+
    | NOAA |
    +------+
    | 1.26 |
    +------+
    1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

The error returned is ERROR 1064 (42000) - Unfortunately I have very deliberately modeled the syntax on published examples. This is just a hobby project and the only thing at stake here is my continued ignorance. Suggestions for a better way - whatever it might be - always will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a semicolon
After DEFAULT 0

Also you need the NEW. prefix to address the columns of the inserted row

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trend_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON Marsh FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE LASTREAD decimal(3,2) DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT NOAA
        INTO LASTREAD
   FROM Marsh
   WHERE time in (select max(time) from Marsh);
   IF NEW.NOAA > LASTREAD THEN
        SET NEW.state = 'flow';
   END IF;
   IF NEW.NOAA < LASTREAD THEN       
        SET NEW.state = "ebb";
   END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That absolutely did the trick. I "abandoned" the NEW.X syntax a few thousand tries ago - not sure what led me there but I guess that's what you get with over-eager amateurs Thanks so much for the help!